# vbs save and close powerpoint presentation

Tags: vbscript, save, powerpoint

I am trying to save, then close all microsoft applications, such as word, excel, and powerpoint using VBScript.

I have got word and excel to work:

```
'Word
On Error Resume Next
Set wd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
On Error Goto 0

If Not IsEmpty(wd) Then
For Each doc In wd.Documents
doc.Save
doc.Close
Next

wd.Quit
End If
```

And:

```
'Excel
On Error Resume Next

Set xl = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err Then
If Err.Number = 429 Then

WScript.Quit 0
Else

CreateObject("WScript.Shell").LogEvent 1, Err.Description & _
  " (0x" & Hex(Err.Number) & ")"
WScript.Quit 1
End If
End If
On Error Goto 0

xl.DisplayAlerts = False  

For Each wb In xl.Workbooks
wb.Save
wb.Close False
Next

xl.Quit
Set xl = Nothing
```

Sadly, I have not figured out how to do the same thing with powerpoint. I have researched online, but have not found the answer. Everything I found that worked wasn't using VBScript.

This is the script that I am trying to make work:

```
'PowerPoint

On Error Resume Next
Set objPPT = GetObject("PowerPoint.Application")
On Error Goto 0

If Not IsEmpty(objPPT) Then
For Each doc In objPPT.Presentation
objPresentation.Save
objPresentation.Close
objPPT.Quit
Next

objPPT.Quit
End If
```

When I run this script, nothing happens.

Could anyone help me to fix my script please?

Thank you!

I would appreciate the time and effort spent!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet should get that done by looping through the presentations collection (tested with office 2010):

```
On Error Resume Next
Set objPPT = GetObject(,"powerpoint.Application")
On Error Goto 0

If Not IsEmpty(objPPT) Then
For Each doc In objPPT.Presentations
doc.Save
doc.Close

Next

objPPT.Quit
End If
```

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it!  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Note that VBA <> VBScript. Might want to change the tag to correct that.
Anyhow, you've got the object hierarchy wrong

objPPT is a PowerPoint Application object.

The Application object has a Presentations collection, containing one Presentation object for each open Presentation.
You want to iterate through the Presentations collection.

Try this. I'm guessing at the VBScript syntax from the surface of my VBA brain:

```
On Error Resume Next
Set objPPT = GetObject("PowerPoint.Application")
On Error Goto 0

If Not IsEmpty(objPPT) Then
For Each Presentation In objPPT.Presentations
Presentation.Save
Presentation.Close
objPPT.Quit
Next

objPPT.Quit
End If
```